How to sort and name endpoints in a good way with FastEndpoints and restful?
I use fast endpoints as lib and want to have 3 new endpoints:
GET /Users for all users
GET /Users/{Id} for a single user
GET /Users/Filter/{filter} for a user search with a given filter
Now my actual folder structure is like
Endpoints -> GET -> File
So in that case I would make a "UsersEndpoint" in the Endpoints/GET folder.
But there I would need 3 of them with the same name.
What is a good folder / naming strategy in this usecase?
